# Who is the third person who listens to Shen Xiu's lesson

Tags: tales-of-demons-and-gods

In *Tales of Demons and Gods*, one lesson of Shen Xiu is observed by three people. The identity of two of them is mentioned, they are the vice principal and another teacher. But the identity is of the third person is never mentioned.

I have ideas who the third person might be, but I'm not sure and it is never mentioned again (IIRC).

- Ye Mo
- Ye Zhong
- The principal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a spoiler answer. The third person is number three ranking in the ye family who is in charge of assassination. The character will be reveal in a plot when eliminating the Shen family

Comment: Thank you. And you can hide the spoiler in an answer. As far as I remember, you should prefix the spoiler with ``>!``. The first sentence should still be there because previews ignore the spoiler-"tag".